# What is the O notation of this loop?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

I understand that this is O(N^2):

```
Loop from i=1 to N
   Loop from j=1 to N
      Do something with i,j
```

But what about this?

```
Loop from i=1 to N
   Loop from j=1 to i
      Do something with i,j
```

Is it still `O(N^2)` or `O(N log N)`? I don't really understand how to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is also `O(N^2)`.

N(N-1)/2 ~ `O(N^2)`.

```
i = 1 than j = 1
i = 2 than j = 1 to 2
i = 3 than j = 1 to 3
i = 4 than j = 1 to 4
…….
…
i = N than j = 1 to N

So for total is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + …. + N = (N * (N+1))/2 ~ O(N^2).
```

Answer (score 0):

For second problem, the running time will be `O (1/2 N^2)`, which later becomes `O(N^2)`, as we don't care about the constant in `O` notation. Usually the `log N` algorithm involves dividing the subproblem into half-size of the actual size in each iteration. Take for example merge sort. In merge sort, in each iteration it is dividing the size of the array into half.

Answer (score 0):

Also O(n^2). 
You have to look at the worst case of how long your code will run.
So first loop runs from 1 to N. 
For each iteration of that loop there is second loop, which runs from 1 to i.

And we know that i will be N on the last iteration, hence it will run for O(N*N), which is (N^2)

We ignore constants in big-O notations.

If these concepts are difficult, try googling some tutorials and examples. All you need is some practice, and you will get it.